# Проблемы с Unit-тестом на Python в Windows

Tags: python, cmd, юнит-тесты

Я провожу Unit-тест через модуль unittest. Я запускаю его следующей командой: `python -m unittest "D:\Python\тесты\module_test.py"`.Однако он мне выводит следующую ошибку:

```
ValueError: path is on mount 'D:', start on mount 'C:'
```

Сам файл теста

```
from module import radius
from math import pi
import unittest as unt

class test(unt.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(radius(3,28.274333882308138))
```

содержание файла module.py:

```
from math import pi

def radius(r):
    print(pi*radius**2)
```

Как мне исправить ошибку?

Comment: Run the command python -m unittest test_filename.py .